# ReactJs: How to use refs in stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

*This could be a duplicate, but in none of the thread(which I searched) which is related to this heading have had the solution rather than having the explanation of why it's not possible to use.*

I have to use a component which contains an input text element with a ref.

```
let FormGroup = ({className, ref, value, maxLength}) => {
    return <div className="form-group">
        <div className="form-group-inner">
            <input ref={ref} type="text" class={className} value={value} maxlength={maxLength}/>
            <i className="form-group-helper"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default FormGroup
```

When I reuse it,

```
<FormGroup
    className={'form-control form-control-sm'}
    ref={'maxUserElement'}
    value={'SMM-00012'}
    maxLength={12}
    onChange={this.handleFormControl.bind(this)}
/>
```

I'm keep getting the following console error:

*`Stateless function components cannot have refs.`*

Kindly help me fix this issue.

Comment: This seems to have been discussed at length within the React repo already: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it just by changing the name of your prop. The issue is that your assigning a `ref` on `FormGroup` rather than actually passing it down.

```
<FormGroup
    className={'form-control form-control-sm'}
    inputRef={'maxUserElement'}
    value={'SMM-00012'}
    maxLength={12}
    onChange={this.handleFormControl.bind(this)}
/>

...

<input ref={inputRef} type="text" class={className} value={value} maxlength={maxLength}/>
```

Though it's not clear why you'd really want to do this unless you are manually finding the DOMnode later, since otherwise your `FormGroup` component still doesn't have any direct access to the underlying `input`.

Also, [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936#issuecomment-247749687) from the [React GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936) raised about this gives a good explanation of the underlying issue:

> a ref, which essentially, a backing instance, can only be returned
>   from a stateful component or a DOM, but not a stateless component,
>   because there is no instance created for a stateless component.